# Google Analytics API - PHP Object vs Array?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I request the API values,  `$results` returns an array, but google is working with `$results` as an object in their example?

The Code is under: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#examples

I always get a

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getKind() on a non-object

Did they change the library and their own example isn't working any more, or is there any error from my side? But I haven't changed the code so far unless the $ optparams values.

PS: Everything is working so far, it´s just about the object / array issue.

I get per `print_r($results)`:

```
Array ( 
    [kind] => analytics#realtimeData
    [id] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga:**censored**&dimensions=ga:medium&metrics=ga:activeVisitors
    [query] => Array (
        [ids] => ga:**censored**
        [dimensions] => ga:medium
        [metrics] => Array (
            [0] => ga:activeVisitors
        )
        [max-results] => 1000
    )
    [totalResults] => 8
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga:**censored**&dimensions=ga:medium&metrics=ga:activeVisitors
    [profileInfo] => Array (
        [profileId] => **censored**
        [accountId] => **censored**
        [webPropertyId] => **censored**
        [internalWebPropertyId] => **censored**
        [profileName] => **censored**
        [tableId] => realtime:**censored**
    )
    [columnHeaders] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [name] => rt:medium
            [columnType] => DIMENSION
            [dataType] => STRING
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [name] => ga:activeVisitors
            [columnType] => METRIC
            [dataType] => INTEGER
        )
    )
    [totalsForAllResults] => Array (
        [ga:activeVisitors] => 752
    )
    [rows] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => DIRECT [1] => 283
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => E-Mail [1] => 5
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => ORGANIC [1] => 287
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [0] => REFERRAL [1] => 92
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [0] => SOCIAL [1] => 49
        )
        [5] => Array (
            [0] => cpc [1] => 23
        )
        [6] => Array (
            [0] => e-mail [1] => 8
        )
        [7] => Array (
            [0] => facebook [1] => 5
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: "on a non-object" means the object you are trying to access is `NULL`.  Are you sure you're getting data back?

Comment: the code is under the url (don´t wanted to blast the site) available, it´s the same.. yes, if i work with print_r($results) i get the real time values..

Comment: So, what does the `print_r` show?  Maybe you are just accessing it wrong?

Comment: I edited the post with the print_r results. i´m not sure, haven´t really changed anything around the accessing. till the following part $analytics is still an object and $results should become an object too?: try {
  $results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:xxxxx',
      'ga:activeVisitors',
      $optParams); 
} Checked it multiple with gettype() during each step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this on the client using the **setUseObjects** method. For example:

```
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

See [Google_Client.php#384](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/Google_Client.php#384) on project hosting.

However, currently it doesn't look like the new alpha version of the [library on GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php) supports this anymore.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem / solution -> Failed by setting the setUseObjects value.. saw it after setting the default to true in the config.php..